# Single tool, ideally open source, for specifying application use cases, requirements, and functional specifications

Tags: documentation-generator, spreadsheet, wireframing, requirements-management, flowchart

Is there a free or inexpensive tool that supports the development of Use Cases (or User Stories), Requirements, and Functional Specifications? I know there is a tendency to blur the lines between these and there are some tools that may perform more than one function, but I view these as distinctly different documents with different purposes. I would like one tool that can do it all. Features might include flow charts, wireframing, ER diagrams, traceability matrix, spreadsheets, and word processing, to name a few.